# What are these blue lines and how do I get rid of them?

Tags: grease-pencil

Was messing with the grease pencil yesterday and this popped up. I have no clue on how remove them.

[image]

Comment: Those seem to be geometry of yet another mesh overlapping with the head.. Probably you converted Grease Pencil into curves or something else.

Comment: @MrZak that does make sense because I did delete a few curves from the outliner, however the blue lines remain.

Comment: Try and hide your main model, and see if its another mesh under that. It could be anything else, so im guessing its probably some Grease Pencil strokes you drew onto your model. Check for that too

Comment: Maybe you didn't delete them all. In anyway it's only guessing what's there at this point. I hardly believe these're Grease Pencil lines as they look in another way in 3d Viewport. Indeed try hiding the head and see what'll be left there; also open Outliner and look whether there're objects locked from editing.

Comment: Also take a look in the outliner, if the mesh is listed there.